# Angular code inside of html strings

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying making the following code working:

```
var td = $(elem).treegrid('getPanel').find('div.datagrid-header td[field="itemtype"]');
        td[0].innerHTML = td[0].innerHTML + 
            '<table style="width:100%;margin-top:-8px;margin-left:2px"><tr>' +
            '<td style="width:18px;text-align:center">' +
                '<a href="" ng-click="getFilteredAssets(filterItemType)">' +
                    '<img border="0" src="all_filter.png">' +
                '</a>' +
            '</td>' + 
            '</td>' +
            '<td style="width:18px">' +
                '<img src="assets_filter.png"/>' +
            '</td>' +
            '<td style="width:18px">' +
                '<img src="projects_filter.gif"/>' + 
            '</td></tr></table>';
```

I am getting images into the place, but clicking on the image with ng-click specified doesn't do anything. Any idea how to make it work?

Thanks

Modified code

```
var element = $compile(angular.element
            ('<table style="width:100%;margin-top:-8px;margin-left:2px"><tr>' +
            '<td style="width:18px;text-align:center">' +
                '<a href="" ng-click="getFilteredAssets(filterItemType)">' +
                    '<img border="0" src="all_filter.png">' +
                '</a>' +
            '</td>' +
            '</td>' +
            '<td style="width:18px">' +
                '<img src="assets_filter.png"/>' +
            '</td>' +
            '<td style="width:18px">' +
                '<img src="projects_filter.gif"/>' +
            '</td></tr></table>')
            )(scope);
        td[0].innerHTML = td[0].innerHTML + element;
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular has no way of knowing you've added some HTML to your DOM. You should use a compile service. It will sweep HTML searching for ng-* directives and so on and apply it to current scope.

```
var element = $compile(angular.element('your html with ng-* directives''))(scope);
```

Then you can insert that element to your DOM.

Comment: I am getting an error: $compile is not a function. I am doing it in a directive.

Comment: What error are you getting? Have you added $compile service to your controller? Please show your angular controller code and is above code inside it?

Comment: I have added $compile to my controller alarms.controller('alarmsController', function ($scope, $compile, ....) Then in the directive I have var element = $compile(  ....... The error: ReferenceError: $compile is not defined

Comment: You have to tell angular that you need this service : alarms.controller('alarmsController', ['$scope', '$compile', function ($scope, $compile, ....) {...}]);. Check this (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) - section Controllers.

Comment: I will try to modify my code but I have another directive and another controller. The following code in that directive works without modification you are talking about: content: $compile('<div><table realtime-services-health></table></div>')(scope), and controller defined like this: home.controller('homeController', function ($scope, ....) {

Comment: Maybe my problem is that a directive and a controller are defined in different files?

Comment: My final html looks like this: "<div class="datagrid-cell datagrid-cell-c2-itemtype" style="text-align: left;"><span>Item Type</span><span class="datagrid-sort-icon">&nbsp;</span></div><a href="" ng-click="getFilteredAssets()"><img border="0" src="all_filter.png"></a><img src="assets_filter.png"><img src="projects_filter.gif">". Clicking on the icon with ng-click specified does not trigger any action.